# Merging 2 arrays using array_merge_recursive not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My database has 2 columns. the person's ID is repeated 5 times in 1 column and each its paired in another column with a question answer
Something like this:

```
ID  Answer
1   A1
1   A4
1   A2
1   A9
1   A3
12  A1
12  A11
12  A12
12  A17
12  A2
```

What i want to try to do is to merge all the answers into 1 array with its ID
something like

```
array (
        [1] => array ( 0 => 'A1', 1 => 'A4', 2 => 'A2', 3 => 'A9', 4 => 'A3'),
        [12] => array ( 0 => 'A1', 1 => 'A11', 2 => 'A12', 3 => 'A17', 4 => 'A2')
        )
```

My code is as follows:

```
foreach ($quiz_answers as $aq => $aa)
            {
                $array_loop = array(  $aa['response_id'] => array( $aa['answer'] ) );
                $ss = array_merge_recursive($array_loop, $array_loop);

            }
```

My Problem is that somehow the loop doesnt merge in the desired way and i only get 2 outputs. I am not very good at manipulating arrays and probably i need another function but i am not quite sure what i am missing. I've tried using another variable in `array_merge_recursive($anotherVariable, $array_loop);` but this doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your `foreach` loop to construct the resulting array how you desire.

```
foreach ($quiz_answers as $aa) {
    $ss[$aa['response_id']][] = $aa['answer'];
}
```

This gives an `$ss` array as you want:

```
array(
    1  => array('A1', 'A4', 'A2', 'A9', 'A3'),
    12 => array('A1', 'A11', 'A12', 'A17', 'A2'),
)
```

Comment: Much better than my solution, it is more concise. Use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to have an array that holds the user ids, each of which is an associative array that holds an array of answers.

```
array (
        [1] => array ( 0 => 'A1', 0 => 'A4', 0 => 'A2', 0 => 'A9', 0 => 'A3'),
        [12] => array ( 0 => 'A1', 0 => 'A11', 0 => 'A12', 0 => 'A17', 0 => 'A2')
        )
```

so something like this will work (skeleton code below)

```
$answers = array();
foreach( $quiz_answers as $id => $ans ) {
  // check if $answers[$id] exists, otherwise create it here....
  if(exists(....)) ...
  else $answers[$id] = array();

  // Then add the current answer to it, as below
  array_push($answers[$id], $ans );
}
```

Comment: even i use array_push instead of array_merge .

Comment: `array_push($answers[$aa['response_id']], array( $aa['answer'] ) ); `return the following error array_push() `expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre />";
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    $output[$array[$i]['ID']][]=$array[$i]['Answer'];
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$quiz_answers = // get all the data from database.
$res          = array();
foreach($quiz_answers as $key=>$val){
     $res[$val['response_id']][]    = $val['answer'];
}

print_r($res);
```